# How to convert a pandas dataframe with non unique indexes into a one with unique indexes?

Tags: python, pandas

I created a dataframe with some previous operations but when I query a column name with an index (for example, df['order_number][0]  ), multiple rows/records come as output.
The screenshot shows the unique and total indexes of the dataframe. [image shows the difference in lengths of uniques indexes and all indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnrs0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the data kept their index when you merged/joined df. Try:

```
df.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you should a df.head()  for example, usually when you consume a data source, if you sent the arg indexto True each row will be assigned a unique numerical index